# Regex for splitting at every character but keeping numbers and decimals together

Tags: java, regex

Ive asked quite a similar question before and implemented this regex: `"(?<!^)(?=\\D)|(?<=\\D)"` to split a `String` like this:

```
String input = "x^(24-3x)";
String[] signs = input.split("regex here");
for (int i = 0; i < signs.length; i++) {
System.out.println(signs[i]); }
```

with the output resulting in: 
`"x", "^", "(", "24", "-", "3", "x", ")"`

Now I need to split a String under the same conditions, but also keeping decimal numbers together.
ATM, an input like `(0.5)` results in: `"(", "0", ".", "5", ")"` but I need the decimal number to stay grouped in one `string` like: `"(", "0.5", ")"`.
Thank you

Comment: Instead of slipping, why not search for something like `\d+|\w+|[^()+-*/]`?

Comment: You might get an answer from somebody... but I have a very strong feeling you are looking in wrong place. If you want to evaluate it later, with nested brackets etc, you should be doing it with proper grammar parser, rather than regex. It is bit more work at start, but pays off very soon and will allow you to cater for future requirements

Comment: @ArturBiesiadowski, regex is a perfectly valid way to tokenize an input stream for a grammar parser.  That's how good old `lex` works, after all.

Comment: `split` is not the right way to solve this, use matching instead.

Comment: Have you considered studying the regex you already have to understand how it works?  Then you could modify it as needed instead of asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: Sorry that Im not fluent in creating regular expressions, but atm it is more important to just get it working instead of studying structure and meaning of regular expressions. Like I didn't try to find one on my own....

Comment: @JohnBollinger But you don't create one uber-expression which splits input into equivalent tokens and then leave problem elsewhere - you prepare dedicated regexp to recognize specific tokens. I don't think that while doing math parser you would ever want to match both number and () brackets in same lex rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting in between the tokens, you could quite easily define a regex matching the several different tokens, for example something like `[0-9]+|[a-z]+|[()^*/+-]`, i.e. one or more numbers *or* one more more letters *or* any single special character. In practice, this may require a bit more elaboration, e.g. to account for decimal numbers:

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)|[a-zA-Z]+|[()^*/+-]");
Matcher m = p.matcher("exp(42) * x^(24-3x) - 3.14");
while (m.find()) {
    tokens.add(m.group());
}
```

Result for `tokens` is `[exp, (, 42, ), *, x, ^, (, 24, -, 3, x, ), -, 3.14]`

Taking a closer look at the components of the regex:

- `(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` Some digits, optionally followed by a dot and more digits. If you also want to allow numbers such as `.1` or `42.` you need to change this a bit.
- `[a-zA-Z]+` One or more letters; if you want to allow variables with underscores or digits, such as `var_23`, you might extend this to something like `([a-zA-Z_]\w+)` (not tested)
- `[()^*/+-]` A single special character, such as an operation or a bracket. Note that the `-` comes last so it is not interpreted as a range. If you also have multi-character operators, such as `!=` or `<=`, you could change this to another disjunction: `+|-|==|<=|...`

Comment: What about the decimals? In my example, 0.5 still is split to `"0", "." , "5"`

Comment: This answer takes account for decimals.

Comment: @Zi1mann I already added something for the decimals. See the example.

Comment: Instead of downvoting my question and arguing in the comments you  worked something out and helped me. Thank you.